# How to analyze a photo entered by a user using a Teachable Machine

Tags: javascript, image, teachable-machine

I am requesting an image from the user's device and then I want to analyze it. I managed to create a separate code for requesting an image and a code for analyzing an image, but I can't combine them.  The Teachable Machine refuses to analyze the image. Below I attach the code for requesting an image from the user and the code for analysis

**HTML:**

```html
<body>
    <input type="file" id="image_input" accept="image/png, image/jpg">

    <div id="display_image"></div>

    <script src="1.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

#display_image{
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const image_input = document.querySelector("#image_input");
var uploaded_image = "";

image_input.addEventListener("change", function(){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        uploaded_image = reader.result;
        document.querySelector("#display_image").style.backgroundImage = `url(${uploaded_image})`;
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
})
```

The code for analysis: (Is there a problem with the `src` line?)

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

<div>Teachable Machine Image Model</div>
<img src="" id="image" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="label-container"></div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@latest/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = "";
    
    let model, labelContainer, maxPredictions;
    let image = document.getElementById("image");

    init();
    // Load the image model and setup the webcam
    async function init() {
        const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
        const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

        // load the model and metadata
        // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
        // or files from your local hard drive
        // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
        model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

        // Convenience function to setup a webcam
        const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // append elements to the DOM
        labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
            labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        }
    }

    async function loop() {
        // update the webcam frame
        await predict();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    // run the webcam image through the image model
    async function predict() {
        // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
        const prediction = await model.predict(image);
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
            const classPrediction =
                prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
            labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
        }
    }
    </script>

    

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to rewrite the code, try to get the `src` of the photo, but all to no avail. The code refuses to analyze absolutely everything.

I expected that the picture inserted by the user would be processed by a Teachable Machine.

Comment: The variable uploaded_image is filled asynchronously, if you tried to access it before it was done loading it would still be an empty string.